# ArrayList data to different table cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, list

I am trying to insert data to table with ngrepeat but no success

I have list with data

```
$scope.chart= {
    labels: [],
    data: []
};
```

if printing out chart.data I get list [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

So, I want to separate comma values from that data list to different table cells with ng-repeat attribute.

I tried smt like this but did not work:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in chart">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.labels}}</td>
            <td>{{item.data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Probably there is something wrong in my controller?

Comment: Yes, you both might be right. Need to change this tag. Thanks

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a row for each data point/label combination and the arrays are the same length you can loop over one of the arrays and use the index to target the other array values

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in chart.data">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{chart.labels[$index]}}</td>
            <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `chart.data[$index]` instead of `item` ?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared little example how to manage with some lists. Hope it'll help you. Here piece of code with simple lists.

```
this.chart = {
  labels: ['january', 'february', 'march'],
  data: ['5 users', '6 users', '3 users']
};
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.chart.labels">{{label}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.chart.data">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Follow extended example with two dimensional arrays on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-bvnaer?embed=1&file=home/home.html)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and labels part is working as it should. It means it prints each item from list to different cell in table. 
Though, if I try to ng-repeate my data array then it only gives me [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
into the first cell. I would like to separate them.

labels (which are number of dates 1-31) and then below/up to them data results for each day.

Comment: @Aleks I've changed my example on stackblitz, try to add
 
`<td ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.chart3.data track by $index">{{item}}</td>`
you can read more about track by $index here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640160/what-is-track-by-in-angularjs-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change your data structure. It feels like you have key-value pair label-data. So it should be something like this:

```
$scope.chart= 
[{
   label: '', //1,2,3,4,5,
   data: '' // your data
}]
```

And then you can try this:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in chart">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.label}}</td>
            <td>{{item.data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then how you populate your chart:

```
var item = { label: 1, data: 'foo'}
$scope.chart.push(item)
```

Comment: there are no objects in the `data` array

Comment: That structure doesn't make sense. There is only one element in the `chart` array that way so `item.labels[$index]` is itself an array

Comment: if to follow author intentions, he wants to iterate through something which has a collection of labels and data

Comment: Also working as version which is suggested above. The problem is that I still can't get data to different cells. I have labels which are number of dates (1-31) and I then data for each day in arraylist. I only get [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] array into the first cell. How to separate them

Comment: @Aleks that data for each day in arraylist, is it an array? Basically, you have a KeyValue pair. Some data bound to the day(1-31). How does that data look like? Is it string, object or array?

Comment: List data = new ArrayList<>();
int[] days = new int[...]; this is where labels come from